# Query entries by nested collection elements in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb, nosql

I'm new to RavenDB and I'm struggling with this simple (i guess) issue. 
I have a Subscriber with a collection of Subscriptions. And I want to make search by Subscription's fields, and return related Subscriber.

Here are simplified class examples:

```
public class Subscriber
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public List<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}

public class Subscription 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string EventType { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried to make an index, as it is said in RavenDB docs:

```
    public class Subscriber_BySubscription : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Subscriber>
    {
        public Subscriber_BySubscription()
        {
            Map = subscribers => from subscriber in subscribers
                                 from subscription in subscriber.Subscriptions
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     subscription.EventType,
                                     subscription.QueueName
                                 };
        }
    }
```

But I'm not sure that this is what I need, since query by collection using `Select` and `Contains` doesn't work. Moreover, the code looks so ugly that I feel that this is not the way how it should be.

So, I'd like to query Subscriptions by EventType, and have corresponding Subscriber as a result. In LINQ it would look like this: `subscribers.Where(x => x.Subscriptions.Select(c => c.EventType).Contains(myEventType))`

Answer (score 1):

Managed to do it. Here is the right index:

```
    public class Subscriber_BySubscription : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Subscriber>
    {
        public class Result
        {
            public string EventType { get; set; }
        }

        public Subscriber_BySubscription()
        {
            Map = subscribers => from subscriber in subscribers
                                 from subscription in subscriber.Subscriptions
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     subscription.EventType
                                 };
        }
    }
```

And that's how it should be used:

```
var results = uow.Session
    .Query<Subscriber_BySubscription.Result, Subscriber_BySubscription>()
    .Where(x => x.EventType == eventType)
    .OfType<Subscriber>()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Note that this would be better:

`Map = subscribers => from subscriber in subscribers
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     EventType =  subscriber.Subscriptions.Select(x=>x.EventType)
                                 };`

This generates just a single value per document, avoiding fanout